# FindInstance: How does it work for linear inequalities?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I have a set of linear inequalities, rational coefficients.
When `FindInstance` returns `{}`, does that really mean there is no solution?
In other words, are the inequalities provably unsatisfiable? The documentation
seems to suggest that:

> With exact symbolic input, `FindInstance` gives exact results.

Does `FindInstance` compute the region of solutions and determines that the
region is empty? Could it miss some boundary solution? Is it using linear programming?

Comment: What does `Reduce` give you?  If there are no feasible points, I would expect it to return `False`

Comment: @mikado: I killed `Reduce` after 45min and my laptop fan on high. :-) Maybe I should let it run overnight.

Comment: It uses linear programming over rationals. Which can be slow. If inequalities are all non-strict then it should not miss boundary solutions, and if it does, that would be a (fairly severe) bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: This is useful information. Now I know a certain lemma is true. Thank you!

Comment: If FindInstance with exact input returns {} and issues no messages that means it has rigorously proven that there are no solutions (unless there is an implementation bug, but linear and polynomial cases are quite well used/tested). Reduce[Exists[vars, ineqs]] would likely use the same method as FindInstance and should be equally fast. Reduce[ineqs, vars] has to find all solutions, so it would likely use cylindrical algebraic decomposition, which is much slower.

Comment: @AdamStrzebonski: Meanwhile, I have paper-and-pencil proved the theorem that `FindInstance` was telling me must be true. Thanks for elucidating `Reduce`.